# Обработка нажатий на цифровую клавиатуру

Tags: c#, winforms, клавиатура

День добрый, друзья!
Пишу программу, в которой можно задавать горячие клавиши на действия. И столкнулся с проблемой в цифровой клавиатуре. Если нажать например на `0` (на *цифровой клавиатуре*), то в `textbox` в событии `KeyDown`, `e.KeyCode` будет иметь значение `Keys.NumPad0`, а если нажать на `SHIFT + 0`(на *цифровой клавиатуре*) то `e.KeyCode = Keys.Insert`, а `e.Modifiers = Keys.None` и `e.Shift = false;`

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Shift && e.KeyCode == Keys.NumPad0)
  {
    MessageBox.Show("SHIFT + NumPad0");
  }
}
```

Путем экспериментов выяснил, что ОС при нажатии шифта и `NumPad0` преобразует его в `Insert`, а если быть точным, программно "отжимает" `Shift` и заменяет эту комбинацию на `Insert`. Поэтому добавил в метод `KeyDown` условие

```
if (e.Modifiers == Keys.Shift)
{
  _FlagShiftPressed = true;
}
```

а в методе KeyUp

```
if (e.Shift == false & e.Modifiers == Keys.Shift)
{    
  _FlagShiftPressed = false;
}
```

Таким образом получилось обработать любые нажатия на цифровую клавиатуру с любым модификатором. Но после этого вылез подводный камень. При нажатии на `SHIFT`, отпускании и последующем нажатии на `Insert`(например) то получаем результат как при нажатии на `SHIFT+0`(на цифровой клаве).
Т.е. в событии `KeyUp`, при отпускании `Shift` не сбрасывается флаг и обработка идет как будто нажата цифровая клавиатура.
Если не понятно выразился, то можно посмотреть на примере задания "горячих кнопок" в свойствах ярлыка.
Как можно обойти данную проблему, или может есть другие более рациональные пути решения?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нашел решение здесь же, на [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28001179/get-correct-keyboard-scan-code-for-arrow-keys), и пока работает без ошибок. Приведу его здесь для уменьшения степени энтропии. 
В моем случае проверяю сканкоды на соответствие след. кнопкам: `Insert`, `Home`, `PageUp`, `PageDown`, `End`, `Left`, `Up`, `Down`, `Right`.

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{

  switch (msg.Msg)
  {
    case WM_KEYDOWN:
      {
        int lParam = msg.LParam.ToInt32();
        int scanCode = (lParam >> 16) & 0x000000ff; // extract bit 16-23
        int ext = (lParam >> 24) & 0x00000001; // extract bit 24
        if (ext == 1)
        {
          scanCode += 128;
        }

        if (scanCode == 210 || scanCode == 199 || scanCode == 201 
            || scanCode == 209 || scanCode == 200 || scanCode == 203 
            || scanCode == 205 || scanCode == 208 || scanCode == 207)
        {
          _FlagShiftPressed = false;
        }
        break;
      }
  }

  return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```