# Как привязать клавишу клавиатуры к button С# form?

Tags: c#, winforms, button, клавиатура

Подскажите пожалуйста, как привязать клавишу клавиатуры к button С# form? Событие Click уже занято. А KeyPress не пойму как работает. Пишу калькулятор.

Comment: Для начала посмотрите тут http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/555402/198316, вопрос там по другому поводу, но в ответе есть нужное вам. Если ни кто подробно не отпишется, вечером постараюсь расписать работу с клавиатурой в формах. Тут вообще много информации на эту тему, но искать надо по кусочкам.

Answer (score 4):

WinForms и клавиатура, довольно веселое сочетание, особенно когда пытаешься их заставить работать согласованно.

**1. События Control.Key***

Любой контрол умеет реагировать на нажатия клавиш и для этого определены несколько событий: [**Control.KeyDown**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown(v=vs.110).aspx), [**Control.KeyPress**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress(v=vs.110).aspx), [**Control.KeyUp**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control.keyup(v=vs.110).aspx). Вроде бы все нормально, подписываемся на события и получаем реакцию на клавиши. Но тут есть один подвох - **эти события срабатывают только когда контрол находится в фокусе**. Кроме того, многие контролы уже имеют стандартные обработчики клавиш, многие реагируют на пробел как на клик, а `TextBox` и его родственники перехватывают почти всю клавиатуру.

**2. Форма тоже контрол**

Класс `Form` также наследуется от контрол, и умеет получать эти события. Вроде бы очевидно, переносим обработку клавиш в события формы и радуемся, она же вроде бы всегда в фокусе. Но и тут не все так просто. Если дочерний контрол настроен на обработку клавиш и находится в фокусе (а если на форме есть дочерние контролы, то один из них обязательно в фокусе), то форма просто игнорирует нажатия на клавиши.

Можно вспомнить о свойстве формы [**Form.KeyPreview**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview(v=vs.110).aspx), которое предназначено для перехвата событий, тогда события клавиатуры будут сначала передаваться в форму. Это вроде бы рабочий вариант, но если вы не хотите чтобы стандартный функционал контролов все еще работал, то придется не забыть выставить свойство `KeyPressEventArgs.Handled = false;` чтобы после обработки события клавиатуры на уровне формы, оно было передано в дочерние контролы. Честно говоря, это не самый лучший вариант, т.к. имеет свои ограничения и далеко не все задачи можно решить таким способом. Хотя он вроде для этого и задуман.

**3. Нас спасет меню**

Первый вариант решения проблемы относительно без шаманства - добавить на форму меню в лице [**MenuStrip**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.menustrip(v=vs.110).aspx). Меню сделано таким образом, что к каждому его элементу, можно привязать хоткей, а для их корректной работы меню перехватывает все события клавиатуры и отдает дальше только те, которые не связаны с нажатиями на заданные клавиши и сочетания. Способ всем хорош, кроме пары моментов: для всех нужных клавиш и сочетаний нужен пункт в меню и необходимо само меню на форме. Если первая проблема еще может быть решена применением скрытых элементов (лично не проверял), то вторая - реально проблема, т.к. не любая форма приложения допускает наличие на ней меню, а добавлять его только ради обработки клавиш... ну вы меня поняли.

**4. Универсальное решение**

Не торопитесь радоваться, все предыдущие пункты требовали только мастерского владения кликом мыши в интерфейс конструктора, а тут потребуется писать код.

В форме, как и любом контроле есть виртуальный метод [**ProcessCmdKey**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control.processcmdkey(v=vs.110).aspx), который отвечает за дефолтную обработку событий клавиатуры, вот его-то и потребуется переопределить в нашей форме для получения ожидаемой и корректной работы с клавиатурой.

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    //ваша логика тут
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

Вызов базового метода - не обязателен. За передачу события дочерним контролам отвечает результат работы метода, только логика немного наоборот: true - клавиша обработана, дальнейшая обработка не требуется; false - событие будет передано дочерним контролам, даже если вы выполнили какую-то предварительную обработку. Таким образом вы получаете полный контроль над обработкой событий клавиатуры на уровне формы или кастомного контрола.

Преимущество данного метода заключается еще и в том, что вы получаете доступ к параметру `keyData`, который, в отличие от `KeyPressEventArgs` содержит не только отображаемый символ, а всю информацию о нажатой клавише, включая скан-код, состояние клавиш-модификаторов и другую полезную информацию. За то, какое именно событие произошло, отвечает параметр `msg`, который содержит системное сообщение WinAPI. Нас интересуют относящиеся к клавиатуре [**WM_KEYDOWN**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms646280(v=vs.85).aspx) и [**WM_KEYUP**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms646281(v=vs.85).aspx). Событие KeyPress - фактически последовательное получение WM_KEYDOWN и WM_KEYUP.

**5. Ну и как этим воспользоваться?**

Да собственно как и обычно. Нажатие на клавишу и клик по кнопке это действие пользователя, которое должно вызвать какую-то реакцию программы. Реакцию описываем отдельным приватным методом, а в обработчики клика кнопки и нажатия на клавишу кладем вызов этого метода. Такой подход избавляет от необходимости копировать код, сводит код обработчиков событий к минимуму, позволяет вызывать заданную реакцию программы любым нужным способом, будь то клик по какому либо контролу, выбор чекбокса или радио-баттона, клавиша или сочетание, пункт меню или все сразу. Код реакции находится в одном месте и при необходимости его изменить не придется думать где еще вы его забыли поправить.

---

Если хватит энтузиазма, позже соберу в этом ответе ссылки на связанные вопросы с хорошими ответами. А пока первое что нашлось по теме без глубокого копания:

[Как правильно перехватывать нажатия клавиш в Windows Forms (C++)?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/554844/198316)
[Обработка нажатий на цифровую клавиатуру](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/433606/198316)

Comment: А можно ли сделать так что бы protected override bool ProcessCmdKey своим свитчем ссылался на, например, private void keyZero_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)?

Comment: @JohnShepard нет, перенесите код из обработчика в отдельный метод и вызывайте в обработчике и свиче. Это займет не так много времени, но избавит от головной боли в дальнейшем

Answer (score 3):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то вы можете использовать событие `KeyDown`. При нажатии на кнопку <kbd>пробел</kbd> выполнится код кнопки

```
private void button1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space)
        MessageBox.Show("Hello!");
}
```

Comment: Мне это не подходит. У меня все кнопки(формы) заняты `private void keyZero_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text += (sender as Button).Text;
        }` То есть кнопки(формы)

Comment: на пробел кнопка по дефолту реагирует как на клик когда в фокусе.