# Горячие клавиши для button

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть кнопка возвращения назад. Как для нее сделать горячую клавишу?

```
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (webBrowser1.CanGoBack)
      webBrowser1.GoBack();
}
```

Comment: [Здесь](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/573976/184217) собраны несколько вариантов.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нужно перегрузить метод [`ProcessCmdKey`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control.processcmdkey(v=vs.110).aspx) и вызвать метод, навешенный на Вашу кнопку:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if (keyData == Keys.Escape) // к примеру клавиша Esc
    {
        button6.PerformClick(); // вызываем метод нажатия кнопки (имитация нажатия)
        // button6_Click(null, null);  // или вызываем метод, навешенный на кнопку
        return true;
    }
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}

private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // чего-то тут делаем
}
```

Сочетание клавиш делается так:

```
if (keyData == (Keys.Alt | Keys.X)) // это сработает на Alt+X
```

Несколько горячих клавиш и разные комбинации сделать можно, просто добавьте несколько условий внутрь метода `ProcessCmdKey`, перегружать несколько раз не нужно, к примеру такие условия:

```
if (keyData == (Keys.Alt | Keys.X))
{
   // Нажали Alt+X - делаем какие-то действия
}
else if(keyData == Keys.Escape)
{
   // Нажали Escape - делаем какие-то действия
}
```

Comment: А как сделать сочетания клавиш?

Comment: И еще вопрос. Если мне нужно сделать несколько горячих клавиш, то нужно каждый раз заново перегружать метод / использовать ваш код для каждой отдельной клавиши?

Comment: @River, смотри обновление ответа. Добавил сочетание и объяснил про несколько горячих клавиш.