# Отключить / включить возможность использовать горячие клавиши menustrip C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Здравствуйте. Имеется menustrip, для полей которого выбраны горячие клавиши через свойство shortcutKeys. Можно ли как-то программно запретить работу горячих клавиш в зависимости от значения переменной bool типа?
Я пытался делать так:

```
if (Properties.Settings.Default.flagKey == true)
            {
                this.KeyPreview = true;
            }
            else
            {
                this.KeyPreview = false;
            }
```

Но такой способ работает лишь для горячих кнопок, прописанных вручную, а не через свойства.

Comment: да препод хочет в курсаче в "настройках" программы сделать включение / выключение горячих кнопок. Для обычных button я все это сделал, теперь вот с этим мучаюсь. А если прописать горячие клавиши вручную, это будет работать для menustrip? Там ведь, если проводить аналогии с button тем же, отключить их действие можно кодом, что я привел выше. Да, winforms

Comment: Я так понимаю, без полотен кода или каких-нибудь нечеловеческих костылей тут все равно не обойтись? Если так, то, наверное, будет проще донести преподу мысль о том, что это перебор и "немного" не мой уровень)

Comment: protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
        {
            if (keyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.O))
            {
                openTorrent();
                return true;
            }
            return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
        }

Comment: Если так написать, то все работает. Этого будет достаточно?

Comment: Подчистил комментарии, в них больше нет необходимости

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Прописанные в `ToolStripItem` сочетания клавиш могут не работать только в двух случаях: отключен соответствующий `ToolStripItem` (`Enabled = false`) или все сочетания перехватываются глобально, на уровне формы. Поведение определено в WinAPI.

Если у вас фиксированный набор горячих клавиш, то можно сделать перехват на уровне формы и блокировать дальнейшую обработку клавиш из этого набора.

Для этого потребуется переопределить виртуальный метод формы - ProcessCmdKey

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if (!Properties.Settings.Default.flagKey)
    {
        if(keyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.O)) return true;
        //Возврат true означает что клавиша была обработана и 
        //не требует дальнейшей обработки 
        //и так для каждого сочетания, в принципе можно заменить на switch 
        //или более сложное условие if
    }
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

Можно пойти и обратным путем. Все необходимые сочетания клавиш определить и обрабатывать в этом методе, а все свойства и прочие способы задания горячих клавиш выпилить из кода совсем. Решение радикальное, но иногда оно проще поддержки зоопарка способов задать горячие клавиши в различных компонентах, включая сторонние.

Ну и связанный [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/573976/198316) - будет полезен в общем контексте вопроса

Comment: Спасибо) значит все правильно сделал