# Не работает завершение процесса по кнопке

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

При нажатии на кнопку должен завершаться определенный процесс. Сначала это работало, но потом перестало. Хотя код не менялся.

```
 public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var materialSkinManager = MaterialSkinManager.Instance;
        materialSkinManager.AddFormToManage(this);
        materialSkinManager.Theme = MaterialSkinManager.Themes.DARK;
        materialSkinManager.ColorScheme = new ColorScheme(Primary.BlueGrey800, Primary.BlueGrey900, Primary.BlueGrey500, Accent.LightBlue200, TextShade.WHITE);
    }
    private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Shift)
        {
            Process[] proc = Process.GetProcesses("Spotify");
            foreach (Process process in proc)
                process.Kill();
        }
    }
    private void materialButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        notifyIcon1.Visible = true;
        this.Hide();
    }
    private void notifyIcon1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        notifyIcon1.Visible = false;
        this.Show();
    }
    private void выходToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
```

Comment: если код не менялся, то поменялось что-то извне кода -- в операционной системе. Например спотифай обновился и сам процесс начал называться по-другому. Или же ты обрубил права программе. Или ще еще тысячи других вариантов. Здесь нужен дебаг. При чем дебаг конкретно на твоем компьютере.

Comment: А сам код завершения процесса правильный?

Comment: Самое забавное если я уберу привязку к кнопке. То он заработает.
Типо вот так:
                Process[] proc = Process.GetProcesses("Explorer.exe");
                foreach (Process process in proc)
                    process.Kill();

Comment: Ставьте брейкпоинт внутрь функции, да отлаживайтесь. Может быть что угодно, вплоть до того, что вы убрали обработчик события с формы и он просто не отрабатывает. А если отрабатывает, то идите по шагам и разбирайтесь, что не так.

Comment: Дебаг так же ничего не показывает.

Comment: Обработчик события висит на форме? В функцию дебаг заходит или нет?

Comment: Обработчик висит , Дебаг работает

Comment: Все дело в кнопке. Когда на форму ставлю обычную кнопку то оно перестает работать

Comment: Форма не может держать фокус. Когда на форме нет других контролов (например, кнопок), способных удерживать фокус, тогда событие `Form1_KeyUp` работает. Если на форме есть хоть одна кнопка, она перехватывает фокус и то событие формы перестаёт работать.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/573976/184217

Answer (score 0, accepted):

И так полазив в коде я понял что причина этому обычная кнопка.

```
private void materialButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        notifyIcon1.Visible = true;
        this.Hide();
    }
```

У меня установлен пакет на Material Design от google и была установлена кнопка от него. После того как я определил, что работе кода мешает кнопка, Я ее убрал.И заменил на стандартную от VSS , но после смены кнопки так же ничего не заработало. Но если убрать кнопку то все работает. Решение: Нужно привязать действие к кнопке через события и все.