# Как в классе Form заставить работать свой UserControl?

Tags: c#, winforms

Всем привет! Как заставить работать в классе Form собственный UserControl? Решила создать свой UserControl, чтобы в классе Form не было лишних нагромождений кода. Создала отдельный класс:

```
public partial class MyControl : UserControl
```

В этот класс закинула часть кода.
Однако теперь этот Control не откликается на нажатие клавиш.
В форме вызываю его так:

```
var control = new MyControl();
```

И добавляю в коллекцию других контроллеров:

```
Controls.Add(control);
```

Он вроде отрисовывается, но не реагирует на нажатия клавиш, хотя должен, ведь основные методы, отвечающие за это прописаны, да и до переноса кода в отдельный UserControl все работало.

Comment: Что значит "не реагирует на нажатия клавиш"? События клавиш не доходят до связанных с ними контролов? Каким способом обрабатываются события клавиш? Есть несколько способов обработки нажатий на клавиши с различным результатом и сопутствующими эффектами, но тут без подробностей с вашей стороны ничего конкретного сказать не могу. Идеальный вариант - минимально достаточный образец для воспроизведения вашей проблемы.

Comment: вот [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/573976/198316) еще посмотрите, и по ссылочкам в ответе и комментариях к тому вопросу тоже.

Answer (score 0):

Приветствую, я предполагаю что возможно элемент управления не был добавлен в коллекцию формы.

```
System.Windows.Forms.Form form = new System.Windows.Forms.Form();    
var control = new MyControl()
{ //пример
   Width = 200,
   Height = 200,
   Text = "Кнопка"
} 
form.Controls.Add(control);
```

Comment: Извиняюсь, забыла уточнить, это я тоже сделала